# Trouble with custom PHP extension

Tags: php, c, apache, arduino

A couple of months ago, I built a serial connection library in C for the Arduino Micro-controller.  I was thinking about how awesome it would be if I could write a PHP wrapper for the library.

I wrote a PHP extension with just one function called "acm_get_door()," which should either return a -1, 0, or 1, depending upon the status of a certain pin on my Arduino.  If it returns -1, then that means that the connection wasn't set.

So after loading up the custom extension and changing both of my php.ini files, and restarting everything else, I ran this test via the CLI:

> $ php -r 'echo acm_get_door();'

It returned a '1'.  I was excited, so I played with the circuitry to see if I could get a '0'.  Well I did and I thought my extension was working perfectly.

I then went to a .php file in my test webserver (same computer) and tried to run the function.  I got a '-1' result from it.  The extension does load, but I can't seem to initiate a connection to the Arduino.

I am wondering if it might be a permissions thing regarding access to certain files.  The function needs to get access to a file called "/dev/ttyACM0"  which it is able to in the CLI version.  It is possible that my Apache web server doesn't have the permissions to access that file, and if so, how would I be able to adjust stuff so that it does?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What does `ls -l /dev/tty/ACM0` tell you?

Comment: Just trying that right now.
It game me:
crw-rw----

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the group has permissions to read/write the device.

Therefore, find out the group owner of the device using `ls -l /dev/tty/ACM0`.  Then, add yourself to the group using:

```
sudo adduser <me> <the_group>
```

(where **me** is your username and **the_group** is the group of the device)

You might need to log out/in to gain the effect of the changed group permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'll be sure to try this out next time.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks to John Jesus, I just had to change the permissions of the file /dev/ttyACM0.

It was set to 660, 666 seems to work (though it it probably a bad idea).

Comment: What is the group owner of `/dev/tty/ACM0`?  Can you post the whole output of the command?

Comment: You can add yourself to the same group instead of changing permissions (see my answer).

Comment: @John, the output is: crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Mar 17 15:39 ttyACM0 == it resets every time I unplug the Arduino.